# Extract value from one file and insert it into another file replacing some other value

Tags: shell, shell-script, sed, awk

I have two files, whose line numbers are not same. But in `file1` I want to replace lines taking reference from `file2` using `sed` command.

In `file1`:

```
tid.infno := 72
tid.setnr := 120 (This number 120 is wrong and It will be 110)
tid.typeidc := 2
tid.typeidm := 1
writedb
clear
```

In `file2`:

```
tid.setnr := 110 (This is correct and I want to place this number in file no. 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `awk` solution:

```
awk 'FNR==NR&&$1=="tid.setnr"{x=$3} NR!=FNR{if($1=="tid.setnr"){$3=x}print}' file2 file1
```

- First part: `FNR==NR&&$1=="tid.setnr"{x=$3}`: Run through `file2` and search for `tid.setnr`, if found the a variable `x` to the value (`110`).
- Second part: `NR!=FNR{if($1=="tid.setnr"){$3=x}print}`: Run trought `file1`, search for `tid.setnr`, and if found replace the 3rd field (`$3`) with the found number in the other file.

Answer (score 0):

First extract number from file-2 and save it as a variable:

```
correctNo=`grep -oP "setnr\s\:\=\s\K\d+" file2.txt`
```

Then replace this number in the file-1:

```
sed -re "s/(setnr\s\:\=\s)([0-9]+)/\1$correctNo/g" file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$ for line in `cat file2.txt`; do
pattern= `sed "s/\s*:=.*//"`
sed "s/$pattern.*/$line/" file1.txt > file3.txt
done
```

The code will create file3.txt with lines from file1.txt, any lines that match the pattern from file2.txt will be replaced with the lines from file2.txt

I make quite a few assumptions here... the above will look for "tid.setnr" in file1 and replace the entire line with the line from file2.txt